# How do I handle Google DLP rate limiting when using the Java library?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dlp

At one point when doing some testing with the Google DLP Java library, I got an exception that indicated that I had exceeded the API rate limit. Unfortunately I don't have the stack trace anymore, so I can't give any more detail at this point. However, it made me realize that I'm not handling that situation in the code. What is the recommended way of dealing with this from a Java application? I haven't seen any examples in the GitHub repo that gives any guidance on this. I'm aware of the ability to request quota increases, and I have already put in a request. My question is on how to gracefully handle this in the code, should I run into the quota exceeded situation again. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It depends greatly on your design and place in which you are making the call from.

- Can you afford to retry until it succeeds?
- Are user's waiting on the response and errors are not acceptable?
- Is this a batch pipeline working offline where taking longer is okay?

If you never want to hit the error, you'll need to implement your own client side rate throttling with accompanying monitoring to assure that you know it's time to request more quota.

If you can retry and wait, try retrying using exponential backoff.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is this documented in the API? It was a surprise to me. Haven't seen anything about rate limiting in the Javadoc.

Comment: It's common across all Google APIs ...in this case it's at https://cloud.google.com/dlp/limits and a similar page exists for each Cloud API ... because of how these clients are created the javadoc only will tell you part of the story.

Comment: Understood. However, for customers using the Google DLP Java library, Javadoc would be the most appropriate way to document the Java classes/exceptions, etc. For example, is there a particular exception thrown specifically for rate limit throttling? I feel that the Java API needs better documentation. Having a generic REST service and a slew of not so thoroughly documented libraries in a variety of languages isn't making integration all that easy for customers.

Comment: I have filed a bug with our tech writer to see how we can improve links between the two. In the mean time, RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED errors are usually 429's. A good source https://cloud.google.com/apis/design/errors